# Blazor Navigation Menu - add picture and a Text Line

Tags: blazor, navbar

I am trying to modify the Blazor Web App Side Navigation Menu - to add a Picture and a single text line

I have modified the NavMenu.razor file as indicated below

```
<div class="top-row ps-5 navbar navbar-dark">
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
        <img src="/MyLogo.jpg" width="150px" alt=""/>
        <br />
        <h4>@Minimal Unit</h4>
    </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

The height of the logo is approximately 80px.

What happens is that the top-row remains too small to fit the image and text

[image]

I have tried a number of things to get the navbar-brand area to be larger including

In NavMenu.razor.css

Added the css line
 `height:200px`
to **.navbar-brand** and to **.top-row** in NavMenu.razor.css

I also tried adding/replacing to the same location - also to no effect.

```
min-height: 200px;
```

Finally, I tried making the changes within the NavMenu.razor file itself

```
<div class="top-row ps-5 navbar navbar-dark" height="300px">
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="" height="300px">
        <!--<img src="/EnviroSenseLogo.jpg" width="150px" alt=""/>-->
        <img src="/Logo.jpg" width="150px" alt="" />
        <br />
        <h4>@EWBlazorWebApp.deviceData.DeviceName</h4>
    </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Also to no effect. Any ideas where I am going wrong.

Comment: Save the .css files and maybe hit F5 in the Browser?  This is a css question so post the css. And then 1 change at a time.

Comment: "_Added_ the css line  `height:200px`" is already strange, you should have _replaced_ a line. In the .top-row  selector only.

Comment: Tried F5 - reload in browser to no effect. There were no pre-existing height, min-height etc. settings in .top-row or ,navbar-brand

Comment: Then specify the versions and exact template names.  Blazor Web App 8 has `height: 3.5rem;`  in both `.top-row` elements.

Comment: I am using 8.0.2, and it is a 'Blazor Web App project'. You are correct, it did have a     `height: 3.5rem;` I had erased it while making modifications to the code, In any case setting it to any other value (15rem, 300px etc.) does not change the visual output al all

Comment: Then it is a case of No Repro: I can adjust that toprow to any height I want. Just by editing the `NavMenu.razor.css` file.  You can use the dev tools to see what styles are in effect (or why not).

Comment: Well, with that in mind, I went to a backup of 1 weeks ago, before any of the attempted changes were made, and then I was able to get it to work, by changing the .top-row height. Not sure what the problem was, possibly some other conflicting changes that were made ?? Works now however.

Comment: Best thing now is to _delete_ this question.